# Como é possível um mesmo endereço de memória ter 2 valores diferentes ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

Me surgiu uma dúvida sobre o comportamento do qualificador de tipo *const* do C++.

Eu estava testando o quanto uma variável declarada como constante está protegida de alterações. Para isso eu tentei alterar o seu valor usando um ponteiro não constante.

E aí surgiu um comportamento estranho pra mim. Eu consigo alterar e printar o valor apontado pelo ponteiro, mas a variável original continua com o valor constante. É como se o mesmo endereço de memória tivesse 2 valores... Como isso é possível?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int a = 1;
    int *p1 = (int*) &a;

    (*p1) = 42;

    cout << p1 << " " << (int) *p1 << endl;
    cout << &a << " " << (int) a << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0x7fff46c6b00c 42
0x7fff46c6b00c 1
```

Comment: Você ta modificando uma constante escrevendo num endereço de memória reservado para tal. Acredito que esteja caindo num Undefined Behavior, já que você "enganou" o compilador.

Comment: Nem sempre o que você escreve e a mesma saída linha por linha no compilador, ele faz diversas otimizações pra seu código rodar teoricamente da melhor maneira possível. inclusive em alguns compiladores tem como desativar essas funções de otimização

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> É como se o mesmo endereço de memória tivesse 2 valores... Como isso é possível?

A resposta curta é: Isso não é possível. Acontece que quando você mandou imprimir o valor da variável `a` seu programa não leu novamente na memória qual valor guardado lá, ele retornou o valor direto.

Esse resultado é devido a uma otimização que o compilador fez. Quando você usa `const` há possibilidades de otimização de desempenho que podem ser exploradas porque o compilador sabe que você não vai mudar o valor dessa variável. Mas aí você foi lá e deu uma rasteira no compilador.

---

### Vamos a Investigar

Testei compilar com o clang e o sanitizer para detectar undefined behaviour, mas ele não viu problemas. Mesmo assim não sei se podemos afirmar que não é undefined behaviour.

Eu testei compilar com gcc++ e com o clang++, ambos passando as opções `-g -O0`, e mesmo assim o resultado foi o mesmo. Ou seja, é uma otimização tão "básica" (por que não fazer?) que o compilador está fazendo mesmo quando você pode o mínimo possível de otimizações com a opção `-O0`.

Vamos olhar o assembly gerado pelo compilador para confirmar. Para isso eu usei o código abaixo para evitar carregar a biblioteca iostream (mais linhas no assembly). Note que agora estamos interessados no valor de retorno da main.

```cpp
int main() {
  const int a = 5;
  int *p1 = (int *)&a;

  (*p1) = 9;

  return a;
}
```

Com o `const` esse programa tem um valor de retorno de 5 (errado) e sem o `const` de 9 (correto). Agora vamos ver o assembly (você pode passar a opção `-S` na hora de compilar para ele parar no passo de assembly).

Com o `const` o g++ gerou o seguinte assembly na minha máquina (compilado com `g++ -O0 -S main.cpp`.

```
    .file   "main.cpp"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $32, %rsp
    movq    %fs:40, %rax
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movl    $5, -20(%rbp)
    leaq    -20(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
    movl    $9, (%rax)
    movl    $5, %eax
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rdx
    xorq    %fs:40, %rdx
    je  .L3
    call    __stack_chk_fail@PLT
.L3:
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Arch Linux 9.3.0-1) 9.3.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Agora vamos remover o `const` e ver o assembly gerado.

```
    .file   "main.cpp"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $32, %rsp
    movq    %fs:40, %rax
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    movl    $5, -20(%rbp)
    leaq    -20(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
    movl    $9, (%rax)
    movl    -20(%rbp), %eax
    movq    -8(%rbp), %rdx
    xorq    %fs:40, %rdx
    je  .L3
    call    __stack_chk_fail@PLT
.L3:
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Arch Linux 9.3.0-1) 9.3.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Bom, eu não entendo quase nada de assembly, mas se olharmos o diff desses dois códigos a única diferença é em uma linha (22). Com o `const` a linha 22 é

```
movl    $5, %eax
```

e sem o `const` a linha 22 se torna

```
movl    -20(%rbp), %eax
```

Viu a diferença? Quando a variável `a` não é const o valor dela, como qualquer outra variável é lido da memória quando precisamos dele (`-20(%rbp)` (o -20 aqui é um ofsset em relação ao ponteiro, no caso rbp que é um ponteiro de frame indicando que essa variável esta na stack) que é onde a variável `a` foi armazenada), mas quando ela é `const` o assembly gerado possui o valor **literal** da variável `a` quando ela foi declarada, que é uma das maneiras de como o g++ trata constantes, com maiores otimizações o compilador simplesmente coloca o valor literal da constante sempre que ele for usando, assim nunca consultando a memoria, trazendo grandes benefícios enquanto a eficiência.
Para maiores informações você pode ler [esse FAQ](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/const.html), também vale checar a [documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) e essa [pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812875/how-const-keyword-works-in-c) tem várias respostas interessantes.

---

Fato interessante: Recentemente encontrei [essa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382501/what-is-the-purpose-of-stdlaunder) no stackoverflow sobre o `std::launder` (eu não conhecia) que serve para você pegar o ponteiro de um objeto para o qual você passou o ponteiro. Resolvi testar com o código aqui e percebi que `*std::launder(&a)` ou simplesmente `*(&a)` vai ler o valor correto na variável `a` porque primeiro pega o endereço de `a` e depois ver o valor armazenado nesse endereço.

Comment: Muito interessante esse comportamento do compilador! Obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: Tentar modificar o valor de um objeto que foi inicialmente declarado como constante é considerado comportamento indefinido pela standard. Então, mesmo usando `std::launder`, o programa ainda estaria errático. Aqui está o parágrafo relevante: http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.cv#4